# How does kubernetes know where the image is when using YAML?

Tags: kubernetes

I was following this tutorial https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/configuration/configure-java-microservice/configure-java-microservice-interactive/

After packaging the mvn projects, I'm asked to deploy them by using the following YAML file with the following command

```
kubectl apply -f kubernetes.yaml
```

This are the contents of kubernetes.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: system-deployment
  labels:
    app: system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: system
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: system
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: system-container
        image: system:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9080
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health/ready
            port: 9080
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 3
          failureThreshold: 1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: inventory-deployment
  labels:
    app: inventory
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: inventory
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: inventory
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: inventory-container
        image: inventory:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9080
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health/ready
            port: 9080
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 3
          failureThreshold: 1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: system-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: system
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9080
    targetPort: 9080
    nodePort: 31000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: inventory-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: inventory
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9080
    targetPort: 9080
    nodePort: 32000
```

I don't have any experience with this kind of YAML files. I don't see any path to the mvn /target folder. But both the applications are now running in kubernetes and I can internally curl the different applications and get a reply.

It's undoubtely linked somehow because it just doesn't work if I don't package the mvn projects, but I'd like to know which part of the YAML finds the artifacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type

```
docker info
```

you'll see something like

```
 Name: minikube
```

in the output: this means that your docker builds are done by the minikube daemon.
This is the same daemon that runs the containers for kubernetes deployments so what's happening is that, when you `kubectl apply` the YAML config, the daemon already has the image locally: it doesn't need to pull it from a registry.

Comment: You're totally right. Paying more attention could have helped because I can see that when I run the mvn package -pl command, it says that the image is being created under the system:1.0-SNAPSHOT name. Now I wonder why mvn package creates a image but I guess that's some sort of convention over configuration when a Dockerfile exists on the project folder..?

Comment: That's the dockerfile-maven-plugin configured in line 141 of the pom.xml. I don't see any executions configured there so they might be configured in the parent POM.